# Lightning:openFiles event alternatives for communities

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community

we need to open (preview) files in communities by clicking on link. After searching I found `lightning:openFiles` event, but in documentation is written that it is no longer recommended and it should be replaced with `lightning navigation service`. But when I look into the documentation, I found that the `filePreview` page is not available in community.

So does someone an idea how we can achieve this? Can we use `lightning:openFiles` event in community since there is no alternative? Or it will be deprecated and removed in future?

Thanks for any advice.

EDIT: We need open preview directly after click on link, without next click or doing any action.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the ContentDocumentId of the file, then use `lightning:fileCard` to display the preview of the file. This is compatible with Lightning communities

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:fileCard fileId="069XXXXXXXXXXXX" description="Sample Description"/>
</aura:component>
```

Refer to full documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileCard/documentation)

Comment: well, I forgot mention that we need directly open preview.

Comment: @sunny hmm its not very clear, at some point in time the user will have to initiate an action. could you edit your question further to elaborate a bit more about the expected behavior of the file preview ? do you mean that file preview should display on page load ?

Comment: I did. We need open preview when user click on link, not on page load

Comment: did you try this [filecard open asmodal popup](http://sfdcmonkey.com/2018/10/29/open-files-lightning-component/)?

Comment: @sdandamud1 yes, I tried. But in this case you need 'click' on small preview to show full screen preview. We need show preview without showing them modal and requiring next click on it.